# Issue with reading instance of Eureka server with DiscoveryClient

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, distributed-system, spring-cloud-netflix

Trying to register my application with `eureka.instance.appname` on Eureka Server, it's getting register

like:  `eureka.instance.appname=orderDetailsApplication    ---> successfully register with Eureka Server`

Once register successfully **trying to read all register application with DiscoveryClient**, **but not able to read it , it's coming empty**

`List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstances = discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceId);`

serviceInstances is coming as null.

Checked  library of DiscoveryClient it's only reading `spring.application.name`, but don't want to register all application with `spring.application.name` with eureka server because we are using common name for all the application.

How can I read all register  application instance with DiscoveryClient?? Can someone please help me??

Comment: Two questions, why do you have the same spring.application.name for all applications? How specifically are you using `DiscoveryClient`? Are you using it directly? Can you show how you use it?

Comment: same spring.application.name for all application is done in config server itself, so can't we change it.  DiscoveryClient we need to autowired and get all instance like:List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstances = discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceId);

Comment: coming from configserver doesn't make sense as a reason. `getInstances()` uses `getInstancesByVipAddress()`. Can you see what is in `/eureka/apps` for vipaddress. It should be what is in `eureka.instance.appname`. What version are you using?